phpunit - mock without using injection?
I'm learning phpunit and noticed lots of example out there seems to mock a class then injects it to another class then to test the method. I wonder what if I want to test it without injection?
Right now, I want it to fail so I know it's using the mock return value but the test passed cause it's not using the mock value. How can I make it to use the mock part? Thanks.
Here's a simple examples:
class Check
{
    public function checkAdd($num1, $num2)
    {
        $sum = $num1 + $num2;
        $calculator = new Calculator();
        $res = $calculator->add($num1, $num2);
        return ($sum == $res);
    }
}
class Calculator
{
    public function add($num1, $num2)
    {
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }
}

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../Check.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../Calculator.php';

class CheckTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testValidateAdd()
    {
        $calculatorMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Calculator::class)->getMock();
        $calculatorMock->method('add')->willReturn(3);

        $check = new Check();
        $result = $check->checkAdd(5, 2);
        $this->assertTrue($result);
    }
}


As checkAdd is using a concrete implementation of Calculator
public function checkAdd($num1, $num2)
{
  $sum = $num1 + $num2;
  $calculator = new Calculator(); // !! HERE !!
  $res = $calculator->add($num1, $num2);

  return ($sum == $res);
}

you won't be able to replace it with a test double (mock,stub,etc).
In order to use a test double you have to handle it to SUS (system under test) somehow. In your example something like:

Create a constructor for Check and pass the calculator
Pass the calculator to checkAdd function (I won't go for this; neverthless wanted to share)

Now that you know why is not working and how to tackle it, let's analyze your code.
As Calculator has no side effects (it's a pure function) and is not an external dependency (like db, filesystem, network, api, etc) it's not strictly necessary to use a test double to replace it. Keep in mind that every time you use a test double you're putting somehow some extra effort in test maintainance (as if you change the implementation is very possibile you need to change test code as well).
The other side of the coin, with your implementation, is that you're creating an object and using it in the same snippet of code. This means you're creating a coupling between Check and Calculator. This isn't a bad design choice per se, just wanted to highlight.
As a side note, someone could say that using a concrete implementation would violate the grounding principles of unit testing as people tend to have confusion about what a unit is and what test in isolation means. To explain it with just few words: a unit is just the code you're testing, so could be a method, a whole class and - maybe suprisingly - even a combination of more than one object. Isolation means you can run tests in different order, maybe in parallel, without one affecting the other and without "external" deps (filesystem, databse, network and so on)

I know how to do it if I pass the calculator in construct but I don't want to pass calculator. As per my question, is it possible to do it without injection. That's why I post this question as I'm learning. Are you saying you can't do the mock on Calculator without changing the classes or you don't know?

@sparkmix you can’t. I stated in the answer.

Thank you. Yea I was thinking maybe it can't but not so sure.
